# Framework Error No such module found in Xcode 7 beta 2

Tags: ios, xcode7-beta2

I am facing the problem since Xcode 7 beta 2 but it was running perfectly in Xcode 6.4. I have my Frameworks folder in the project and it is in the project directory. This Frameworks folder contains all the frameworks needed, but when i import this framework i get error "No Such Module Found". I have even set the Framework Search Paths but i am not able to get rid of that error.

But i am able to run the application.

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of the Xcode window showing the missing framework and/or the framework search paths?

Comment: Or at least tell us what module is missing.

Comment: @trojanfoe Fabric framework is missing.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann in framework search paths i have added (PROJECT_DIR) as the framework is in project directory.

Comment: And you have `Fabric.framework` configured in the *Link Binary with Libraries* setting?